# Finding Non Matches MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

I managed to import a whole load of xml files into database table called "trans"
with the help from here: 
[Extracting XML data into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472008/extracting-xml-data-into-mysql/24472061#24472061)

I wanted to create some additional checks, importing unique xml>database, also delete anything that is in the database that doesn't match from database>xml, keep a list of all non matching entries.

I have managed to get xml>database check to work, importing only unique new transactions.

But sometimes at month end I need to check if the database is still up to date with a new up to date monthly xml file. I need to list everything that does not match the new xml an again to delete them.

How can one achieve this using PHP?

```
Current Database
custID      Name        Product
2           john        P2
8           mark        P3
9           craig       P3

New XML
custID      Name        Product
2           john        P2
7           sarah       P4

Expected Updated Database
custID      Name        Product
2           john        P2
7           sarah       P4

Database does not match xml
custID      Name        Product
8           mark        P3
9           craig       P3
```

The only thing I can come up with is to get non matching entries in database is to do a left outer join and locate using null values.

Is this the right way or is there a simpler way or more elegant way to do it?

Here's the select statement

```
select a.custID, b.custID from trans a
left outer join transtemp b on b.custID=a.custID
where b.custID IS NULL
```

Comment: The `left outer join` with a `where` clause checking for `NULL` is a perfectly reasonable solution.

Comment: So there is no default matching function in sql between tables I'm missing?

Comment: You could also use `not exists` or `not in` in the `where` clause.  Typically, the `left outer join` solution performs well in most databases.

Comment: Ok so select statement is fine to select a whole load of results, but how would I delete from the table in a where statement with multiple null values?

Comment: . . If you edit your question with the code for the `select` statement, it will be much easier to specify the `delete` statement.